Can you define the exponential function without using natural powers?
The most common definitions of $e^x$ (with $x\in\Bbb R$) that I have seen are
$$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$$
and
$$e^x=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$
Now, both of these definitions require $x^n$ to be defined for $(x,n)\in\Bbb R\times\Bbb N$. Of course, it's very easy to define such expression, but today I was wondering whether it's possible to define $e^x$ without using natural powers, and then derive natural powers from such definition.
Does the definition of $e^x$ as the unique function such that $e^0=1$ and $(e^x)'=e^x$ work? Are natural powers needed in the proof of existence or uniqueness of such function?
Thanks in advance.

Yes, you can define $e^x$ as the (unique) solution of $\begin{cases}y'=y\ y(0)=1\end{cases}$, see also this

Seriously, I don't understand the purpose of the question. We might as well try to write a book without the letter t. You know for sure that everything you will do rely on natural powers. Also the answer posted, and of course any theory of differential equations. The question could be made more meaningful if you define a specific (!) number system in which in fact natural powers are not available and then ask how to define the exponential function.

@MartinBrandenburg I was curious about this possibility. A book without the letter T would be fun to read.

There's another approach that doesn't involve uniqueness of solutions to ODEs, but instead uses material that might come before any discussion of $e$ in a calculus book.

Define $L(x) = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} ~dt$. Observe that $L$ is defined for all $x > 0$.

Note that by the fundamental theorem, $L$ is differentiable (and hence continuous), and $L'(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, which is always positive, hence $L$ is an increasing continuous function.

Observe that $q = L(3) > 1$ by taking a lower-sum for the integral with stepsize $1/4$ (I think that suffices!).

Observe that $L(xy) = L(x) + L(y)$. To do this, fix $y > 0$. Then split the first integral into the integral from $1$ to $x$, and then integral from $x$ to $xy$; then perform substitution on the second, replacing $t$ by $t/y$, and the result follows.

Show that $L(3^n) > n$, and $L(3^{-n}) < -n + 1$ for any $n$, and conclude (with the intermediate value theorem, if you want to get fancy) that $L$ is a surjective function from $\mathbb R^{+}$ to $\mathbb R$.

Conclude, using the inverse function theorem, that $L$ has an inverse function $E$ from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^{+}$, and that $E$ satisfies $E'(x) = E(x), E(x+y) = E(x) \cdot E(y), E(-x) = \frac{1}{E(x)}$, etc.

Define $e$ to be $E(1)$, and observe that for any rational $r$, we have $E(r) = e^r$.

This shows that the exponentiation function $r \to e^r$, defined on the rationals, has a continuous extension to the whole real line, which is necessarily unique. So we define $e^x$ (for arbitrary $x$, whether rational or not) to be $E(x)$.


It's true that this derivation uses one "natural power", namely $t^{-1}$ in the definition of $L$, but presumably this is OK with you. It uses other natural powers to show that $E$ and rational-exponentiation agree, but it's hard to imagine any other way to do that than using the definition of rational exponentiation.

BuT yOu HaVe UsEd NaTuRaL pOwErS in step 5. (Seriously, I don't understand the purpose of the question. We might as well try to write a book without the letter t.)

OK. I admit it. I guess I did. On the other hand, I could have just showed how to estimate $L(k)$ for large $k$ with a lower sum. I agree the question was a little vague, but that's how questions are --- when you don't thoroughly understand something, it's easy for your misunderstanding to sneak into the way you express your questions. (See almost any question about probability for a demonstration of this!). I like to be forgiving and try to guess what OP might be getting at (and perhaps clarifying areas of misunderstanding, if I can guess what they are), but realize that not everyone does so.

@JohnHughes what's vague about the question? I'm trying to improve the quality of my questions, so any insight would be appreciated.

"without using natural powers" is a bit vague. If I compute $3 \times 3$, am I actually 'using squaring'? I think Martin's comments kind of get at this. The construction I gave does mention $3^n$, but only as a quick-and-dirty way to prove that $L$ is surjective. Without powers, it can be difficult to specify large numbers. Log increases very slowly, so to show it takes on a value of at least n, I need to go out to $x = e^n$... but "not using natural powers" means I can't say that. The construction itself uses no natural powers, but the proof does...does that count? To my eyes, that's vague.
